# What is the shortcut to move between two Terminator tabs?

Tags: command-line, terminator, navigation

[image: Terminator tabs]

When I open Terminator, I can move two Terminator in same tab using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

How to move between two Terminator tabs?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

- go to next tab: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>pgdown</kbd>
- go to previous tab: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>pgup</kbd>

---

Key commands in Terminator

- Toggle fullscreen: <kbd>F11</kbd>
- Split terminals horizontally: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- Split terminals vertically: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
- Close current Panel: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
- Open new tab: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
- Move to the terminal above the current one: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>
- Move to the terminal below the current one: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>
- Move to the terminal left of the current one: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>
- Move to the terminal right of the current one: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

This maybe useful.

Comment: The shortcut for a different terminal emulator may be different. For instance, I am using Sakura terminal emulator , which uses Alt+arrow keys

Comment: Konsole uses Shift+arrow keys.

Comment: I don't see the point of copying the text from my answer to your answer.

Answer (score 36):

Here are some useful commands form [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Terminator) for the *Terminator*:

> <kbd>F11</kbd> Toggle fullscreen
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> Split terminals horizontally
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> Split terminals vertically
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> Close current Panel
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Open new tab
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> Move to the terminal above the current one
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> Move to the terminal below the current one
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> Move to the terminal left of the current one
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> Move to the terminal right of the current one

You cal also check out the settings to see all Keyboard shortcuts or to set your own shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for including arkwiki link, it helps me although my issue is different.

Answer (score 6):

1. `vi ~/.config/terminator/config`
2. set up

```
------------ before ------------ 
[keybindings]
    switch_to_tab_1 = 
    switch_to_tab_10 =
    switch_to_tab_2 = 
    switch_to_tab_3 = 
    switch_to_tab_4 = 
    switch_to_tab_5 =
    switch_to_tab_6 =
    switch_to_tab_7 =
    switch_to_tab_8 =
    switch_to_tab_9 =

------------ after ------------ 
[keybindings]
    switch_to_tab_1 = <Alt>1
    switch_to_tab_10 =
    switch_to_tab_2 = <Alt>2
    switch_to_tab_3 = <Alt>3
    switch_to_tab_4 = <Alt>4
    switch_to_tab_5 = <Alt>5
    switch_to_tab_6 = <Alt>6
    switch_to_tab_7 = <Alt>7
    switch_to_tab_8 = <Alt>8
    switch_to_tab_9 = <Alt>9
```

In the Terminal window, right click on mouse, select **Preferences > Key settings > switch_to_tab_1~10 keybinding > Enter shortcut to use**

Answer (score 4):

Although I like @incBrain response because he provides several shortcuts, in order to move between terminal tabs, these two work for me:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> Next terminal in the current tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> Previous in the current tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> Next tab

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> Previous tab

Answer (score 3):

Use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PgDown</kbd> or <kbd>PgUp</kbd>.

Comment: not working, but thank your answer